# Sphinx not always returning string attributes

Tags: sphinx

In some instances, Sphinx is returning results without JOIN'd fields I've declared as sql_attr_string's. Take the following source/index configuration for example:

```
source myapp_recipe
{
    type                = pgsql
    sql_host            = 
    sql_user            = me
    sql_pass            = secret
    sql_db              = myapp_db
    sql_port            = 

    sql_query           = \
        SELECT myapp_recipe.id as id, \
            myapp_recipe.name as name, \
            myapp_recipe.cookbook_id as cookbook_id, \
            myapp_cookbook.name as cookbook_name, \
            'recipe' as content_type \
        FROM myapp_recipe \
        INNER JOIN myapp_cookbook \
        ON myapp_recipe.cookbook_id = myapp_cookbook.id

    #content_type for django
    sql_attr_string       = content_type

    # stored string fields in the document
    sql_attr_string     = cookbook_name

    # stored and indexed string fields
    sql_field_string     = name

    # ForeignKey's
    sql_attr_uint       = cookbook_id
}

index myapp_recipe
{
    source          = myapp_recipe
    path            = /var/data/myapp_recipe
    docinfo         = extern
    morphology      = none
    stopwords       =
    min_word_len    = 2
    charset_type    = utf-8
    min_prefix_len  = 0
    min_infix_len   = 3
    enable_star     = 0
}
```

For some searches, result documents are coming back without attributes aside from `content_type` and `name`. For a different search, that returns the same document, Sphinx may very well return the same result document WITH all the expected attributes.

Example:
A query for "pizza" will return an incomplete result document (documentA) without JOIN'd string attributes.

A query for "pizza pocket" will return the same document (documentA) WITH all of the expected JOIN'd attributes.

Can anyone explain this baffling behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you don't have duplicate id's 
Your sql_query  must return a result with unique ids , otherwise Sphinx can have for same id several documents (for Sphinx the id is seen as a simple number , doesn't apply any uniquity rule ) . When you index, there should be raised an warning that you have duplicates.

Comment: I am not seeing any indexing warnings with this configuration. I am searching multiple indexes with a call like this: client.Query("pizza", "myapp_table1 myapp_table2 myapp_table3"). Could that be related to this issue?

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that that's the problem, now that you've put me down this path - the problem seems to occur when I have matches from multiple indexes. Any ideas on how to avoid this issue?

Comment: Since the "document id" is the "id" of the object in postgres, I'm not sure how to avoid duplicate id's when querying multiple indexes.

Comment: The solution is to use AddQuery() on each index that needs to be searched. The one line Query("myquery", "index1 index2 index3") requires that every document in index1, index2, and index3 have unique id's. Since my indexes represent Django model tables, they're going to have duplicate id's. Thanks aditirex.

Comment: So for anyone else's future reference - duplicate id's between tables passed into Query("myquery", "table1 table2 table3") is going to break your search results in mysterious ways. :)

Comment: @patrickn : you didn't said anothing about searching  in multiple indexes. So when you search in severl indexes in one query , the results from  all indexes get merged, elimitating docs with same id ( the one from last index remains). So if you want to search in multiple indexes , make sure you have the ids unique across all.